# Linux Kernel generate compile-commands.json for module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

**The problem**: Most of macro definition and even header files are not looked up by an IDE because include path is not specified in the IDE configuration. It inhibits autocompletion and navigation.

Here is my `Makefile`:

```make
#-Wno-declaration-after-statement
ccflags-y := -std=gnu11 -Wno-declaration-after-statement -Werror
obj-m += pfsw.o
pfsw-objs := src/init.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I ran `make V=1` and noticed that the compile command along with include path is actually pretty cumbersome (counting Linux Specific `-include` for parameters):

```sh
gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write/src/.init.o.d -nostdinc \
   -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include \
   -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated \
   -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi \
   -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi \
   -I./include/generated/uapi \
   -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include \
   -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h \
   -D__KERNEL__ \
   ...tons of options ommitted...
   -c -o /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write/src/init.o \
   /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write/src/init.c
```

**Question:** Is there a way to generate `compile-command.json` to inform IDE about include paths? Or the only solution is to manually pass the include path to the IDE one by one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to CLang has a lot of different tools, including some to analyze the code, the *compile-command.json* is required. That's why Tom Roeder from Google provided a
*scripts/clang-tools/gen_compile_commands.py* in the commit [b30204640192](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b30204640192) ("scripts: add a tool to produce a compile_commands.json file") for this.

Note, kernel must be compiled at least once to make this script work.

P.S. I suppose you are trying MS Visual Studio Code?

Kudos to colleague of mine, Alex, who is user of it and told me about existence of such script.

Comment: So this is not possible to do without compiling the kernel?

Comment: It uses files that are being generated during compilation. I suppose the `make allyesconfig` will give best coverage on the used commands during the compilation.

Comment: @St.Antario hey, at least we don't need to do something like `make clean && bear make` (a full recompile*, no matter how fresh our compile) like we might end up doing *without* the script.  *Assuming you aren't using e.g. ccache to skip actually rebuilding.

Comment: The script is now at `scripts/clang-tools/gen_compile_commands.py`.

Comment: @St.Antario, not sure I have got your comment. It's already in the answer like this. Maybe I'm missing something?