# Why is VSCode's Intellisense unable to parse #if defined(__GNUC__)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, kernel-module

I use Atom, CLion for kernel module development and I'd like to give VSCode a try.

Intellisense can't find some types and macros such as all the `uint*_t`, `u*`, `dev_t`, `DECLARE_BITMAP()`.

After a quick look at the `types.h`, it seems all these types/macros are defined after `#if defined(__GNUC__)`.

- Is it a known issue?
- How to solve that? The kernel headers are full of those `#if defined()`.

Here is my **c_cpp_properties.json**:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "defines": [
                "__GNUC__",
                "__KERNEL__",
                "_GNU_SOURCE",
                "MODULE",
            ],
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/include/**",
                "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include/**"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: "After a quick look at the `types.h`, it seems all these types/macros are defined after `#if defined(__GNUC__)`." - In the [header](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/types.h) I see only `loff_t` and 64-bit types are defined under `__GNUC__`, other types and `DECLARE_BITMAP` don't require this macro. I would suggest to remove final stars (`**`) in the `"/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/include/**"` line and in the line below: Linux kernel has many header files with the same names, and exact path to these files really matters.

Comment: that solves the problem, thanks! I didn't know some files located in sub-folders could override the default ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Kernel generate compile-commands.json for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324820/linux-kernel-generate-compile-commands-json-for-module)

Comment: not completely but it can help one day, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux kernel has many **header files** with the **same names**, but located in the different directories. And exact path to these files really matters.

For that reason it is better to not "glob" (using terminating `/**`) include directories for the Linux kernel but write the **exact** ones:

```
"includePath": [
    # You could glob include directories for your module
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    # .. but do not glob Linux kernel ones
    "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/include",
    # Do not glob arch-specific include directories for Linux kernel too
    "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include"
],
```

Comment: could you add the reason or a link explaining why the `include` folder contains different files with the same name? it looks like a very awkward architecture choice

Comment: One reason of duplicate names of header files is usability of some Linux headers in the user space libraries/applications. While such files are grouped into `uapi/` subdirectory, they require some definitions (types, macros) contained in pure kernel headers. Because of that, Linux kernel contains **two variants** of some headers: one variant is for in-kernel use, and the second variant is for installation for user space. As for `types.h` header specifically, its usage is even more flexible. And I fear I cannot even describe such flexibility.